# Mongo - how do I flatten a class to its string value?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class containing an Id and its associated value. I'd like to map it to a simple string.

When the Example class is met only the value of its Name property should be saved.

Something like

Example s = new Example("2", "second");

s.Upsert()

should save to Mongo
"Example" : "second"

How can I manage to flatten the class structure using `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap`

```
public class Example
{
 public string Id { get; private set; }
 public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: huh? What would you want to map this to? Could post a concrete example?

Comment: @mnemosyn: I've tried to explain it more clearly. When serializing an object of class Example it should serialize ONLY the value Name inside the object.